# ssh -f rejects subsequent X11 apps after the first X11 app is closed

Tags: ssh

Lets say I run an application on remote machine like this:

```
ssh -Xf remote.machine.com xterm
```

Then from the new xterm I open emacs. After I close the initial xterm, the emacs still remains open, but the ssh X11 has stopped working. Now I can't open any other X11 applications like gvim from the emacs terminal. But if I hadn't quit the first xterm I opened with the ssh -f command then it is ok, and the gvim opens. How can I configure ssh to keep the X11 forwarding open even after the first xterm has quit?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `wait` so the connection will not terminate after the end of the first command.

```
ssh -Xf remote.machine.com "xterm; wait"
```

Comment: I don't have `emacs` installed, but I tried to run one and another `xterm` this way and it worked for me without any problems. Can you post also your verbose debug logs?

Comment: did you quit the first xterm and then try opening a third xterm from the second xterm? it shouldn't work. It doesn't for me.

Comment: Yes with these instructions I can reproduce it. Do you have some reasonable use-case for this? It is generally bad idea to start processes and then kill their parents.

Comment: I close the xterm session because I don't need it open. I use shell in emacs. But I use other gui apps. Ofcourse keeping it open is a good idea, but that just kills the dream of finding solutions in life.

Comment: There is still more solution other then your one: You can run first non-X terminal (`bash`) or directly your `emacs`. Or you can use `ControlMaster` option of SSH, so you don't even need the remote terminal and every other app or command will be started over the existing connection. But this is maybe worth investigation, since it can be bug in `openssh`. I will take a note to check the next week.

Comment: I tried the other suggestion for a bash terminal. But that is the same thing. (More windows to manage). Maybe openssh will have a solution for this.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. I have got still quite much of other tasks. But I bookmarked this question and as soon as I will have a minute, I will come  back to it.